# :hover not working on stacked font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to do something very simple, have stacked icons from font-awesome change color when they are hovered over.  I am seeing the inside icon (the question mark) highlight like I want, but the outside circle is not changing color.  HTML and CSS below:

```
//HTML:
<span class="more-info-toggle fa-stack">
<a href="#" id="more-info-share-toggle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Why share?">
<i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-question fa-stack-1x"></i>
</a>
</span>

//CSS:
.more-info-toggle:hover {
    color:#53AB46;
}
```

Any idea why the outside circle isn't changing color?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo. It should be:

```
#more-info-share-toggle:hover {
color:#53AB46;
}
```

The id wasn't matching up, and it should be #.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you target the right elements. try something like this:
and if you use id="more-info-share-toggle" than you'll have to use '#' sign in your stylesheet. If you use class="more-info-share-toggle" you should use '.'

```
#more-info-share-toggle:hover i {
   color:#53AB46;
}
```